# Storing persistent v8 object handles in a hashed container

Tags: c++, v8

I would like to store a `v8::Persistent<v8::Object>` handles in a hash type container (more precisely Google `dense_hash_set`). Do I need to implement my own hasher function for this? Can I rely on the `v8::Object::GetIdentityHash` method for the hash value? Poking at the code I can see that they are basically just generating a random 32-bit number for the object and caching it. Is that enough to avoid hash collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is, yes, it can be used as a hash key, but...

According to [this](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Object.html#a5309f7a349feb906a05ee45b6feeaab1), `int v8::Object::GetIdentityHash()`:

> Returns the identity hash for this object.
>
> The current implementation uses a hidden property on the object to
>   store the identity hash.
>
> The return value will never be 0. Also, it is not guaranteed to be
>   unique.

It maybe generate same keys for different objects, and you may have collisions. However it's not an enough reason to abandon this function.

The problem is keeping collision-rates low. And it depends on distribution of `GetIdentityHash` and size of the hash table.

You can test it and count the collisions and check if it's damages your performance or not?!